# Is there a way to reference mixed format changelog files from the Liquibase master file?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

We have been using YAML for our liquibase changelogs but would like to switch to using JSON.  Is there a way to get liquibase to load changelogs in both yaml and json formats so that we don't have to go through  a conversion process?

If the files have to be converted, how can the converted files be deployed considering that the file hashes are going to change (or perhaps they don't change because the hash is based on the parsed object and not the file format?).

We are using SpringBoot if that matters for configuration.

Comment: `Is there a way to get liquibase to load changelogs in both yaml and json formats so that we don't have to go through a conversion process?` - Have you determined an answer for this?

Comment: ^ Actually, I have just successfully mixed file types (json and sql)

Comment: @pymarco - What version of liquibase are you using and did you have to do anything particular to make it work?

We are using a master with child files.

Comment: I am using Liquibase v3.5.3. Nothing special was needed. The databaseChangeLog file includes both json and sql files. At first it didn't work only because I had a typo in the sql changeset comment.